# Oracle - Performance between Regexp_substr and Instr

Tags: performance, compare, regexp-substr

As my title, somecases I see Regexp_substr faster and less cost than Instr and somecases its opposite.
I don't know when I should use Instr or Regexp_substr, someone can explain for me and tell me benefit of each? The example following:

```
**Regexp_substr:**

SELECT * FROM tabl1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND col1 IN (
 SELECT regexp_substr(abc,'[^,]+',1,level) AS A
 FROM (
  SELECT 001 abc -- replace with parameter
  FROM DUAL
  )
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (abc,'[^,]'))+1 );

**Instr:**

SELECT * FROM tabl1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND INSTR (',' || '001' || ',',',' || col1 || ',') > 0 ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well you look like you might be working with CSV data, so even `INSTR` is requiring a bunch of concatenation operations.  It might be a comparison of bad to even worse for your current query.  In general, the base string functions in Oracle will outperform the regex functions, so you should use the former assuming you can do that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I don't use CSV data, the reason why I use bunch of concatenation operations is select number with varchar datatype, and I have to concatenation comma to fit my condition. In theory, the base functions in Oracle will useful and most benefit than regex function, but this case is not and I want to clear it.